# How to redirect after click on button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this php page within which there are two buttons.

The first button redirects to the next page after submitting the content.

As for the second button, I would like it to submit the content and then close the browser window.

The two buttons are in the same html form with the tag action that redirects to the page for the first button.

Is it possible to combine two functions `submit()` and `location.replace()` like this in the `onclick` attribute of the second button?

```
function saveData(){
    submit(); 
    replaceLocation();
}

function replaceLocation() {
    location.replace("Thankyou.php");
}
```

Comment: `window.close()`? (works only for windows opened by scripts; you cannot close windows that were not opened by a script using a script)

Comment: and if i want to redirect to another page? i have a form with the tag action = "page2.php", so both the buttons redirect to this page. if i want that the second button after clicking on it, submit the content and redirect to a page different from page2.php?

Comment: The browser unloads `form.php` or whatever contains the form, then performs a post request on `page2.php` with the data in the form. Then it waits for `page2.php` to send data back. If `page2.php` sends back a 302 temporary redirect header and a location header, you can redirect the user to an other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is `php` method

```
header( "refresh:1;url=redirect.php" );
```

post this code at bottom of you `php` processing code that code will redirect you to page which you want exactly after 1sec (*change `redirect.php` to ypur page which you want*)